# Residues and congruence

Tags: apl

From the APL book, I am trying to decipher how I could convert in C the computation for 'r' when 'j' is not 0:

> For each set of integers n, j, and b, with b > 0, there exists a
>   unique pair of integers q and r such that
>
> ```
>   n = bq + r,   j ≤ r < j + b.
> ```
>
> The quantity r is called the j-residue of n modulo b and is denoted by
>   b | j n. For example, 3 |0 9 = 0, 3 |1 9 = 3, and 3 |0 10 = 1.
>   Moreover, if n ≥ 0, then b |0 n is the remainder obtained in dividing
>   n by b and q is the integral part of the quotient.

What represents 'j' and how do I get r without resolving by iterating inside the interval?

Then, the rest of the paragraph says that:

> In classical treatments, such as Wright (1939), only the 0-residue is
>   considered. The use of 1-origin indexing (cf. Sec. 1.5) accounts for
>   the interest of the 1-residue.

So I guess `n mod b` in C for example is `b | j n` with j=0, but I don't understand why using 'j=1' would benefit for indexing with 1-origin. How can this be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation, notation, notation.

The notation used in Iverson's A Programming Language predates that which was later implemented as modern APL.

[image: kei apl]

I got this from http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APL.htm

Thus 3 |0 9 with 0 written as a subscript would work today in just about every APL as 3 | 9.

3 |1 9 with 1 written as a subscript is not implemented as such but could be solved as a defined operator. (I used Dyalog 13.1)

```
     ∇ r←x(i mod)y                        
[1]    r←i+x|y-i                          
     ∇                                    

      3 (0 mod) 9
0
      3 (1 mod) 9
3
      3 (0 mod) 10
1

      ⎕io←0
      3 (0 mod) ⍳9
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2

      ⎕io←1
      3 (1 mod) ⍳9
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: PS:  The C definition of modulo differs when using negative integers and non-integers.

Comment: Yes, C definition differs from Python and Java too. Thanks for the great answer. You know your APL!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose N is large (or negative) and you have an array with b < N elements.
You want to index the array with N, but wrap around if N is larger than
the number of elements in the array.

In C, which is 0-origin, you want the index in 0...b-1 (both including).

In APL, which is 1-origin by default, you want the index in 1...b instead.

That's probably what the 1-index is good for. You can compute the 1-origin
from fhe 0-origin without iterations:

if (idx == 0)   idx = b;

Comment: Are you the Jürgen from GNU APL? Thanks for your answer. I just downloaded the latest and I can't seem to be able to compute 'r' with these examples: 3 |0 9 = 0, 3 |1 9 = 3, and 3 |0 10 = 1. It seems that GNU APL won't take the  'j' in the 'b | j n' expression and will always use ' b | n'. Is that correct?

Comment: Q1: yes.If you say b∣j n in APL then it means (b∣j),(b∣n). In GNU APL you get:

Answer (score 1):

Q1: yes.

In `b|j n` the b is scalar-extended to match `j n`. So it is the same as `(b∣j),(b∣n).` **j** is NOT a modifier for **∣**. In other words `b∣j n` is not the j-residue of n, but the 0-residue of j followed by the 0-residue of n.

In GNU APL (and I believe in all other APLs as well) you get:

```
      3∣0 9
0 0
      3∣1 9
1 0
```

From a 0-residue modulo b you can get the j-residue by **adding** `j∣b` to the 0-residue:

```
      +/ 3∣0 9
0
      +/ 3∣1 9
1
```

Comment: Thanks again. In the APL book: 3∣1 9 = 3 but you got: +/ 3∣1 9 = 1 . Why?

Comment: Iverson's A Programming Language?